# How to revoke an upvote?

Tags: support, voting, up-votes

I have wrongly upvoted a question, but when I tried to undo it, it didn't allow me to because of privilege restrictions.

Is there any option to revoke the upvote?

Comment: Just click on the upvote again, provided it was not done a long time ago.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That's only the case if the upvote was done a while ago and is locked in.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Because he has less than the 125 rep required to downvote.

Comment: Yes..When I try to click up vote again "You last voted on this question 11 mins ago Your vote is now locked in"  unless this question is edited" ..So there is no option to revoke the vote after 10 mins.

Comment: @DannyBeckett Yes I need 125 rep to down vote,but what if I wrongly voted up something?:-)

Answer (score 7):

You have five minutes to retract a vote, which you can do by clicking on the same arrow that you just pushed to vote. After five minutes, your vote is locked unless the post has been edited.

We don't want users rescinding votes unless it really was just a failure of eye-motor coordination at play. If you could take back an up vote you made a month ago, the author of the post that lost your vote would be very confused. If you still like the post after 4 minutes and 59 seconds, we take that as a sign that you thought it through.

However, if a post is edited, there's a chance that whatever caused you to vote for it changed, at which point you can rescind your vote and even cast another in the opposite direction. This goes for down votes and up votes, and there's no expiration there - only that the post must first be edited. At this point, the author of the post can be reasonably certain that *something* about the most recent change had to do with the votes changing - much less confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification..At first I didn't know I have to click Upvote twice to undo it..Now it's solved.

Answer (score 2):

Just click the upvote button again to undo:

> [image]

Be quick though, after 5 minutes your vote will be locked in:

> [image]

If there is anything you can edit in the post, do so (unless it is too minor); this will lift the restriction (once your suggested edit is approved)

Comment: What is time-out in SO for locking a vote?

Comment: @Naren five minutes.

Comment: 5 minutes @Naren.